# PostgreSQL: empty BLOB over network

Tags: postgresql, networking, blob, pgadmin

A table shows its BLOBs (bytea column) when accessed from pgAdmin III (v 1.12.3) locally (Ubuntu 11.10), but when accessing the PG over network from remote Windows 7 machine using pgAdmin III (v 1.14.2) table shows all the data but BLOBs. They are looking like empty.

PostgreSQL on Ubuntu machine is "PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1, 64-bit"

Comment: Would seem like a given for such a question that you mention the versions of pgAdmin and PostgreSQL in use?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe seems to be this feature (quoting the [changelog of pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/development/changelog.php)):

> 2006-11-06 DP  1.6.0   Hide binary data (bytea) in the edit grid.

[Here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgadmin-support/2006-11/msg00041.php) is the according thread on the pgAdmin list.

You should be seeing "" in a `bytea` cell of the edit grid. (That's the window titled "Edit Data" you get when you open a table from the object browser.)

In the "Data Output" pane of the SQL editor, the data of a `bytea` column itself is displayed (in escape string notation).

The cell shouldn't be "empty" in either case.

As for version 1.12.3: you might want to install the current version 1.14.3 and see if that changes anything. 1.16 is going to be released with Postgres 9.2 pretty soon, too. Beta is out.